# Low Accuracy with Keras on Example Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano

I have run an example from "Deep Learning With Python", by Jason Brownlee, Chapter 10's "Multiclass classification of Flower Species".I am running it unmodified, with unmodified input data..

The book claims 95% accuracy, but I am getting less than 60% with theano, and less than 42% with tensoflow. I am running this on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM using the latest pip installed keras, and CPU, since I have no GPU to train with. The code includes fixing numpy's random seed.

Here is the output of pip freeze in my virtualenv (using python 2.7):

```
appdirs==1.4.3
cycler==0.10.0
funcsigs==1.0.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
h5py==2.7.0
Keras==2.0.4
matplotlib==2.0.2
mock==2.0.0
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.20.1
pbr==3.0.0
protobuf==3.3.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.12
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy==0.19.0
six==1.10.0
subprocess32==3.2.7
tensorflow==1.1.0
Theano==0.9.0
Werkzeug==0.12.1
```

The code:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:, 0:4].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:, 4]
# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
# define baseline model


def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

What could be the reason for the low accuracy?

Comment: Impossible to said without seeing your code. Maybe overfitting? maybe underfitting?

Comment: We need more information to give correct answers, by the number of input and output nodes, are you using iris dataset? What is your accuracy metric?

Comment: Code added, but it is unmodified, so it shouldn't be an issue of under or overfitting?

Comment: does the book claim, how many training epochs were used for the stated accuracy? if they are not using the latest model you might very well have overtrained

Comment: I can't see anything related to how many training epochs were used, but it seems to suggest that the accuracy the author gets is from running the exact code. What do you mean by "latest model"?

Comment: For how many epochs is it being trained on? I see 200 in the code, but that is the keyword for Keras 1.x, so it might be being trained for only 10 epochs.

Comment: Changing nb_epoch to epochs made accuracy go to > 95%, thank you very much Matias. I am going to file a bug against Keras about this.